# make object sub-prototype have context of parent object

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

This may be a duplicate, and if so, I apologize. I've looked through a few questions and haven't found one that quite matches my situation (which maybe a bad sign to begin with).

I've got a class, say `RandomClass`, that is defined as follows

```
function RandomClass(id){
    this._id = id;
}

RandomClass.prototype.getID = function(){
    return this._id;
}

var rc = new RandomClass(1);
rc.getID(); //returns 1, as expected
```

Say I want to define a set of handlers, and keep them in a sub-object (while continuing to use prototype) of RandomClass. *My knowledge of prototypes is somewhat limited, so apologies if this next bit is extremely bad form.*

```
RandomClass.prototype.handlers = {};

RandomClass.prototype.handlers.HandlerOne = function(){
   console.log("Handler one calling from ID: "+this._id); 
   //the context is not the context of RandomClass, but of RandomClass.prototype.handlers!
}

rc.handlers.HandlerOne(); //prints "Handler one calling from ID: unknown"
```

Again, maybe this is bad form, but I have several handlers which need to be called and doing things this way simplifies the code to:

```
var handler = "one of many many handlers returned from an ajax request";
rc.handlers[handler]();
```

So, my question is **how do I make HandlerOne's context be the context of RandomClass rather than of handlers?** I'd like to continue to use prototypes, because then they are not cloned multiple times (as in the following example):

```
function RandomClass(id){
    this._id = id;
    this._handlers = {};
}

function HandlerOne(){
    console.log("Handler one calling from ID: "+this._id);
}

var rc = new RandomClass(1);
rc._handlers["HandlerOne"] = HandlerOne.bind(rc);
rc._handlers["HandlerOne"]() //prints as expected, but I believe performance is much worse here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both answers submitted at this point are good alternatives (that I would say are acceptable), but I've decided to take another route (that lead to the least amount of modification to my code :)).

Similar to @BlaShadow's answer, rather than passing the context and setting a `parentScope` variable, I simply use Javascript's `function.call()` method to pass the correct context.

```
function RandomClass(id){
    this._id = id;
}

function.prototype.handlers = {}
function.prototype.handlers.HandlerOne = function(data){
    console.log("Handler one calling from ID: "+this._id+" with data: "+data);
}

var rc = new RandomClass(1);
rc.handlers.HandlerOne.call(rc, {"some": "data"});
//prints "Handler one calling from ID: 1 with data { "some" : "data" }
```

Comment: Also, considering the way I asked the question, I hesitate to mark any of the answers (including my own) as "correct". Javascript may not easily permit doing what I had asked, but I'm going to wait a bit to see if there are other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Could satisfy to you do this, instead of bind the context try to pass it as a parameter.

```
function RandomClass(id){
    this._id = id;
    this._handlers = {};
}

function HandlerOne(instance){
    var parentScope = instance;

    console.log("Handler one calling from ID: "+parentScope._id);
}

//call it like this
var rc = new RandomClass(1);
rc._handlers["HandlerOne"] = HandlerOne;
rc._handlers["HandlerOne"](rc)
```

Comment: Hmm... passing itself as the context is interesting, and I believe would work just fine. Thanks for the suggestion! However, I'm still holding out for a way to access the parent context directly.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply make `Handlers` it's own *class*. Note that you should not access private members from outside the *class* like I did in the exemple below. You must expose the correct public API to make objects work together without violating encapsulation.

```
function RandomClass(id){
    this._id = id;
    this.handlers = new Handlers(this);
}


function Handlers(randomClassInstance) {
    this._randomClassInstance = randomClassInstance;
}

Handlers.prototype = {
    constructor: Handlers,

    handlerOne: function () {
        console.log("Handler one calling from ID: "+ this._randomClassInstance._id);
    }
};
```

Then you can do:

```
var rnd = new RandomClass('test');

rnd.handlers.handlerOne(); //Handler one calling from ID: test
```

Comment: Also very interesting, I hadn't thought about moving it to it's own class. I guess there's no reason why it shouldn't be. Could you explain the line `constructor: Handlers` in the `Handlers.prototype` definition?

Comment: @MandM Every function already have a `prototype` which has a `constructor` member that points to that function. Here, since I am replacing the prototype by a new object entirely (to benefit from the object literal notation), I need to set the `constructor` member *manually*. The code would still work without it, but if someone ever relies on `rnd.handlers.constructor`, it wouldn't return what's expected.